# react native modal: Button on press calls a prop function and resets the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, setstate

in parent screen:

```
<CoolName add={function} />
```

in CoolName modal:

```
state={ a: 'some string a', b: 'some string b'}

<Button title="Add" onPress={this.props.add.bind(this, this.state)}/>
```

how can I do this and reset the state (this.setState({a: '', b: ''})) at the same time inside the onPress prop??

Answer (score 0):

Define a callback in the onPress prop. Whitespace is only for readability.

```
<Button title="Add" onPress={() => {
                                    this.props.add.bind(this, this.state);
                                    this.setState({a: '', b: ''});
                                   }
                            }
/>
```

Comment: I tried that, but only the setState is working not the 'add' function

Answer (score 0):

found it, I just needed to delete the first (this) in the bind when using a callback function because its not the same scope :)

```
<Button title="Add" onPress={() => {
                                this.props.add.bind(this.state);
                                this.setState({a: '', b: ''});
                               }
                        }
```

/>